# How to use regex to only keep first n repeated words

Tags: python, regex

If I have an input sentence

```
input = 'ok ok, it is very very very very very hard'
```

and what I want to do is to only keep the first three replica for any repeated word:

```
output = 'ok ok, it is very very very hard'
```

How can I achieve this with `re` or `regex` module in python?

Comment: I would break this into two problems, first you have to find the repeated words, then you have to remove the additional duplicates. I wouldn't solve either problem with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use a capturing group with a backreference and use that in the replacement.

```
((\w+)(?: \2){2})(?: \2)*
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture group 1

  - `(\w+)` capture group 2, match 1+ word chars (The example data only uses word characters. To make sure they are no part of a larger word use a word boundary `\b`)
  - `(?: \2){2}` Repeat 2 times matching a space and a backreference to group 2.  Instead of a single space you could use `[ \t]+` to match 1+ spaces or tabs or use `\s+` to match 1+ whitespace chars. (Note that that would also match a newline)
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?: \2)*` Match 0+ times a space and a backreference to group 2 to match the same words that you want to remove

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N642V6/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LjhY6y)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"((\w+)(?: \2){2})(?: \2)*"
s = "ok ok, it is very very very very very hard"
result = re.sub(regex, r"\1", s)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Result

```
ok ok, it is very very very hard
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group a word and use a backreference to refer to it to ensure that it repeats for more than 2 times:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\b((\w+)(?:\s+\2){2})(?:\s+\2)+\b', r'\1', input))
```

This outputs:

```
ok ok, it is very very very hard
```

Comment: Nice pattern, can you spot the similarities :)

Comment: Change `\s+` to `\W+` and it will work for input like "ok ok, it is very, very, very, very, very hard

Answer (score 0):

One solution with `re.sub` with custom function:

```
s = 'ok ok, it is very very very very very hard'

def replace(n=3):
    last_word, cnt = '', 0
    current_word = yield

    while True:
        if last_word == current_word:
            cnt += 1
        else:
            cnt = 0

        last_word = current_word

        if cnt >= n:
            current_word = yield ''
        else:
            current_word = yield current_word

import re

replacer = replace()
next(replacer)
print(re.sub(r'\s*[\w]+\s*', lambda g: replacer.send(g.group(0)), s))
```

Prints:

```
ok ok, it is very very very hard
```